# Differentiability of $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{|xyz|}$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I need to study this function: $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{|xyz|}$ at the point $P=(0,0,0)$.

I have determined it is **continuous** at P.
That is, $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)} f(x,y,z) = f(0,0,0) = 0$

Also, that its partial derivatives exist and are all zero at that point.

Now, according to the following limit:

$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}{f(x,y,z) - f(0,0,0) - D_f(0,0,0)\cdot(x,y,z) \over{||(x,y,z)||}}  = 0$

$f(x,y,z)$ should be differentiable at $(0,0,0)$. But, is that correct? I know that in a single variable $f(x) = |x|$ is not "soft" at $(0,0)$, it can't be approximated with a line and therefore it is not differentiable. So, if the previous limit is correct, its result would strike me as odd.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that you need to prove that an arbitrary sequence $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ wich converges to $(0,0,0)$ must give the same limit. $\sqrt{|x|}$ has a crease at $0$, I don't even think the partial derivatives exist at $(0,0,0)$...

Comment: Wouldn't that be a consequence of being continuous?

Comment: Yes, but of the derivative being continuous. (Wich is a vector field)

Comment: Note that IF the partial derivatives exists and are continuous, THEN the function is differentiable.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think I am confusing _partial_ with _directional_. The derivatives with respect to x,y and z are 0 at (0,0,0), is that right? It's the derivatives in other directions with would result in conflict?

Comment: I did the directional derivative limit for V=(v1,v2,v3) and I get sqrt(|t|*|v1*v2*v3|), which goes to 0 when t approaches 0...

Comment: Also note really why $|x|$ differntiable at $(0,0)$ is because when you approach from left you get $-1$ but when approach from right you get $1$ and a limit can't have two limit points thus must not be differntiable

Comment: Right. I was having that in mind with this function too, so I thought it would not be differentiable either.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of my earlier comment, but it's not too rigorous, so feel free to comment out!!

Without being too rigorous, you can state that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}|x|=\left\{\begin{array}{rc}1&x>0\\-1&x<0\\?&x=0\end{array}\right.=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\operatorname{sgn}(x)&x\neq0\\?&x=0\end{array}\right.$$

But, if $x\neq0$, then
$$f_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|xyz|}}|yz|\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\sqrt{|yz|}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}}$$
and we could say that:
$$f_x(0,0,0)=\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{|0\cdot0|}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}}=0$$

And $f_y,\,f_z$ follow the same reasoning...

So I'm inclined to believe that the partial derivatives are continous If we define $D_f(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)$ *a priori*.
With that, you can say that the function is differentiable, without calculating the limit you are using.

---

PS: Note that the limit you're using to prove differentiability is not correct. It should say:

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{f(x,y,z)-f(0,0,0)-D_f(0,0,0)\bullet(x,y,z)}{\|(x,y,z)\|}=0$$

as you need to consider the incremental change given by the partial derivatives when increasing the variables.

Comment: You're totally right, I didn't write the increment in the limit because it was multiplied by zero, but it seems incomplete that way (I edited it).

If the differential of a function turns to be zero at the point in study, can you _always_ say it is differentiable without showing further proof?

Now, why is this function differentiable at zero if it has the absolute value in it - which is not differentiable by itself?

Comment: It's not given by the fact that the value of the derivatives is $0$. Is given by the fact that the partial derivatives are continuous. I needed to calculate the limit of the derivatives wo show if they were continous in de neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$, although I dind't specify that in the answer.

Comment: I've got it. I still find it weird that it turned to be differentiable but I think I now understood the logic behind proving it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that this answer is just a guess... Now I have seen the plot of the function $\sqrt{|xy|}$ ([here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3dplot+sqrt%28abs%28x*y%29%29), quite odd), and I don't really think that function is differentiable because it has "spikes" in the coordinate axis. Maybe we need more firepower (a better answer) :P

Comment: You're right, it looks spiky. Couldn't it be that the plane z=0 aproximates it well enough close to zero?

Comment: I don't think so, because the same argument I used on this function could be used on $\sqrt{|xy|}$ to show that the derivatives are 0... I'm not really sure about it either: it was just my try to do it (I stated that it was just too long for a comment). Anyways, I hope this was helpful someway.